# ogr2ogr too many GCP points - exceeds maximum number of characters in the command line

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, windows, command-line

I am trying to adjust a vector polygon dataset using [ogr2ogr spline](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) transformation with cmd commands like:

```
C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:\\path\\output.shp -order 3 -tps -gcp -13163.1627 271026.6107 -13274.2879 271201.236 -gcp 64464.2679538 -210398.439419 64390.5172491 -210240.678326 -gcp 98432.5310433 -181184.99898 98313.298804 -180985.232826 C:\\path\\input.shp
```

Also I try to do this inside Python:

```
import os
control_points = (
"-gcp -13163.1627 271026.6107 -13274.2879 271201.236 "
"-gcp -12706.1672 271461.5611 -12843.4862 271599.4093 "
"-gcp 98432.5310433 -181184.99898 98313.298804 -180985.232826 "
"-gcp 64464.2679538 -210398.439419 64390.5172491 -210240.678326 "
)
command = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe -f "ESRI Shapefile" C:\\path\\output.shp -order 3 -tps ' + control_points + 'C:\\path\\input.shp'
print command
os.system(command)
```

With a few points like this it works fine. 
But actually I have much more control points, more than 1000. I need to use them all because the dataset covers the entire country. And when I write into the command all my GCPs, the Python script doesn't produce any output at all (no errors), and when I paste this command into the Command prompt it just cuts my command and then gives an error from ogr2ogr.

I found out that the [maximum number of characters in the command prompt is 8191](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830473/command-prompt-cmd.-exe-command-line-string-limitation) but my command has 79792 characters.

So, **how can I use ogr2ogr with hundreds of control points?** Is there a way to store them in some batch file or variable? The [GDAL page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) only says that -gcp option may be provided multiple times to provide a set of GCPs, directly in the command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This page](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_utilities.html), which lists general command-line options, says there's an "--optfile" argument:

> Read the named file and substitute the contents into the command line options list. Lines beginning with # will be ignored. Multi-word arguments may be kept together with double quotes.

Putting your GCPs arguments in a text file might let you work around the command-line length limitation.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, it works with `control_points = "--optfile C:\\path\\gcp.txt "` But I don't understand their words about double quotes, because inside the gcp.txt I had to write just `-gcp -13163.1627 271026.6107 -13274.2879 271201.236
-gcp -12706.1672 271461.5611 -12843.4862 271599.4093` without quotes, because with quotes it was not working.

Comment: Glad to hear it works!  Do you have an example of how you were including the quotes?

I would assume that they would work in the same was as on the command line, where `ogr2ogr -gcp "-12706.1672 271461.5611 -12843.4862 271599.4093"` would cause "ogr2ogr" to be argv[0], "-gcp" to be argv[1], and "-12706.1672 271461.5611 -12843.4862 271599.4093" to be argv[2].

Comment: I tried to quote every line `"-gcp -13163.1627 271026.6107 -13274.2879 271201.236 "
"-gcp -12706.1672 271461.5611 -12843.4862 271599.4093 "` like it was in my Python variable. Your example with quoting only coordinates is also not working. Only without any quotes it works.